# better structure for emitting a Socket.io message and waiting for result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

i use `Socket.io` with `Angular.js` like this:

```
//socket emitter
$scope.checkUsername = function (username) {
    $scope.socket.emit('checkUsername', {username: username});
};
.
.
.
.
.
//socket listener
$scope.socket.on('checkUsernameResult', function (result) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            //Do something with result
        });
});
```

I mean, i set a block for emitting and a block of code for listening that can be anywhere in the code or even another file. My question is that: is there any better way to write this?

For example i want to check username availability and i want to write a code that send data and wait for result right there and in it's own structure right when we create callback function in `Node.js`.

I think this way i'm writing the code is not correct. i'm talking about client side(Angular controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");
return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        })
    }
};
});
```

Then for your listeners call functions with your callbacks.

```
function doSomething(req) {
  return true;
}

socket.on('some listener', doSomething(req));
```

And to emit.

```
socket.emit("some emit event", {some: '', stuff: ''});
```